# filtering by date in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm Trying to search for all the items who have a field of date inside a range, and it fails (returns no results)

The query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "last_updated": {
            "from": "2013-01-01 00:00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping:

```
{
    "my_doctype": {
        "_timestamp": {
            "enabled": "true"
        },
        "properties": {
            "cards": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "last_updated": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

results in:

```
 {
        took: 1
        timed_out: false
        _shards: {
            total: 1
            successful: 1
            failed: 0
        }
        hits: {
            total: 0
            max_score: null
            hits: [ ]
        }
    }
```

The same query filtered by a range for an integer field("cards") with a numeric value works fine.
Changing the date to a very early start (1900-01-01 00:00:00) also shows no results.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, I know I have the _timestamp enabled in the mapping, but that is not the field I am filtering by.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Seems to be working fine to me:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "settings": {
        "index.number_of_shards": 1,
        "index.number_of_replicas": 0
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "_timestamp": {
                "enabled": "true"
            },
            "properties": {
                "cards": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "last_updated": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/doc/1 -d '{
    "last_updated": "2012-01-01 12:13:14"
}
'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/doc/2 -d '{
    "last_updated": "2013-02-02 01:02:03"
}
'
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_refresh'
echo
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/test/doc/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "last_updated": {
                        "gte": "2013-01-01 00:00:00"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Thank you. It was a typo on my part - how embarrasing. 

I'm gonna leave the question here and mark as accepted, for reference if someone needs to see the testcase. Or does it make more sense to delete it?

Comment: @eran Fourth match in google for "elasticsearch date search (at least for me). Keep it around, it was useful to me =)

Comment: @Gil could you be more specific? Which part of the query were you talking about?

Comment: @imotov According to http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html the range filter expects `gte`, `gt`, etc, rather than `from`.

Comment: @Gil yes, you are right. `from` is now obsolete. It still works with 1.0 though. I have updated the answer. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: How do you compare as a equals date?

Comment: How to get data between two dates(How to use gte and lte in the query)

Answer (score 0):

### Filtering Data By Date Using (Python)

**Don't Forget to install and Import**
[Python Elasticsearch Client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.4.1/)

```
@app.route('/get-data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getFilteredData():
    uri = f'https://localhost:9200/'
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=uri, basic_auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
    body = {"query" :{"match_all":{}}}
    
    # if the method POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from_date = request.form.get('fromdate')
        to_date = request.form.get('todate')
        body = {
                "query": {
                    "range": {
                        "order_date": {
                            "gte": from_date,
                            "lte": to_date
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    index_data = client.search(index=index, body=body)
    return render_template('index.html',index_data=index_data)
```

**Git Hub LisaHJung**

[Relevance of a search](https://github.com/LisaHJung/Part-2-Understanding-the-relevance-of-your-search-with-Elasticsearch-and-Kibana-)