# elasticsearch, multi_match and filter by date

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, range

It seems I followed every similar answer I found, but I just cant figure out what is wrong...

This is a "match all" query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

..and the results:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "unittest_index_unittestdocument",
                "_type": "unittestdocument",
                "_id": "a.b",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "a.b",
                    "docdate": "2018-01-24T09:45:44.4168345+02:00",
                    "primarykeywords": [
                        "keyword"
                    ],
                    "primarytitles": [
                        "the title of a document"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but when I try to filter that with a date like this:

```
{  
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":{  
                "multi_match":{  
                    "type":"most_fields",               
                    "query":"document",
                    "fields":[ "primarytitles","primarykeywords" ]
                }
            },
            "filter": [
                {"range":{ "docdate": { "gte":"1900-01-23T15:17:12.7313261+02:00" } } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have zero hits...

I tried to follow this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html and this [filtering by date in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643414/filtering-by-date-in-elasticsearch) with no success at all..

Is there any difference that I cannot see????

***Please note that when I remove the date filter and I add a term filter on "primarykeywords" i get the results i want. The only problem is the range filter***

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was no error with my query, **the problem was that the docdate field wasn't index**... :/

Don't know why I initially skipped indexing that field (my mistake), *but I do believe elastic should warn me that I am trying to query something that has "index: false"*

This thing that elastic just doesn't return results without informing what is going on is, in my opinion, a major issue. I lost one day reading everything I could find on the web, just because I didn't had a proper feedback from the engine.

*Fail safe died for this reason...*