# Elastic query to search a term and with in a date range

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
      "filter":{
        "and":[
        {
          "term":{
            "Server": "XYZ"
          },
          "range": {
            "DateTime":{
              "from": "2018-12-13T00:20:48.782Z",
              "to":"2018-12-14T00:20:48.782Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }}
  }
}
```

Above is my elastic query to fetch all records belongs to `XYZ` Server and within the time range, I have `Server` and `DateTime` columns in my dataset but throws below error:

> {   "error": {
>       "root_cause": [
>         {
>           "type": "parsing_exception",
>           "reason": "[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
>           "line": 9,
>           "col": 11
>         }
>       ],
>       "type": "parsing_exception",
>       "reason": "[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
>       "line": 9,
>       "col": 11   },   "status": 400 }

What am i missing here!

Comment: Can you add your index mapping details ?

Comment: You can use `lte` and `gte` to filter the date range query. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15643735/2845389)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is malformed use the following query instead:

```
GET _search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "filter": [ 
      {
        "term": { 
          "Server": "XYZ"
        }
      },
      { 
        "range": {
          "DateTime":{
            "from": "2018-12-13T00:20:48.782Z",
            "to": "2018-12-14T00:20:48.782Z"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `and` in your filter clause. There is no `and` clause in ES query.
Basically, you need to combine filter on `term` and `range` clause. Please read [combine filters in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html) for more information on this.

As your query is using an invalid clause, ES isn't able to parse your query.

Please use the proper query and you should be able to get the results from ES.

Please try below query, which should work fine and let me know if it doesn't work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "Server": "XYZ"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "DateTime": {
                        "from": "2018-12-13T00:20:48.782Z",
                        "to": "2018-12-14T00:20:48.782Z"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're in `filter` context do you need to add also `constant_score` type query?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clearly saying that the query is not correct.

You can check the official docs for [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) and for [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to se that there is no filter inside bool queries and there is not from, to in range queries.

Please check this query.

```
GET _search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [ 
      {
        "term": { 
          "Server": "XYZ"
        }
      },
      { 
        "range": {
          "DateTime":{
            "gt": "2018-12-13T00:20:48.782Z",
            "lte": "2018-12-14T00:20:48.782Z"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
 }
}
```